# How to do test set evaluation using a regression model in Caret?

Tags: r, cross-validation, caret

I'm used to using `Caret` to do classification but now I need to use it for regression.

I have successfully trained a model on my training set but I'm not sure what the next steps are to validate my model against my test set. With classification I've been using a confusion matrix but I can't find out what the equivalent is for regression models.

How should I evaluate my regression model using the test set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic `caret` functions are `postResample` (a horrible name) and `defaultSummary`.